# how to referesh listview after fixed interval of time?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I make demo in which I show data from webservice .Which is working fine .Mean I am able to display data on listview when I hit service first time.But I need hit server again and again and get new data .I am able to get new data .but I need to show new data on listview but my list become blank or empty when I got new data . why ?

here is my code .

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.departure_dashboard);
    Log.d("=========onCreate", "constructor");

    try {
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String message = bundle.getString("Response");
        Log.d("=========onCreate", message);
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
         data = new Gson().fromJson(message, deparaturedaseboarddto.class);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this,  data.getData());

         listView.setAdapter(adapter);
         timer =new Timer();
         timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new alertTask(), 0, 4000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

when Timer start I used alerk task.and call webservice again and again

```
public class alertTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            WebserviceMethod callDepartudeDashboard=new WebserviceMethod();
            callDepartudeDashboard.setObserver(Departuredashboardscreen.this);
            callDepartudeDashboard.getwebService(ConstantVariable.dashboardWebServiceURL+"a/"+"departuredashboard"+"?crsCode=hnh");


        }

    }
```

It is the method which give response again and again ...

```
@Override
        public void getWebserviceResponse(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("timer", result);
            data.getData().clear();


            deparaturedaseboarddto localData = new Gson().fromJson(result, deparaturedaseboarddto.class);
           data=localData
            adapter.notifySetDataChanged();

        }
```

here is my custom adapter for listview

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    ArrayList<deparaturedaseboarddto> deparaturedaseboarddto;
    private Context context;
    public CustomListAdapter( Context context, ArrayList<deparaturedaseboarddto> deparaturedaseboarddto){
        this.deparaturedaseboarddto=deparaturedaseboarddto;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return deparaturedaseboarddto.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_listitem, null);
            }

            final TextView platFormName = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_platform);

            final TextView schDepart = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_schDepart);
            final TextView expDepart = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_expectdepart);
            final TextView arrival = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_arrival);
            final TextView exparrival = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_expertarrival);
            final TextView stationName = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_stationName);

            final String platformValue = deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getPlatformNo();
            final String schDepartValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getSchDepart();
            final String schExpectValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getExpDepart();
            final String arrivalValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getDestSchArrival();
            final String exparrivalValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getDestSchArrival();
           String stationNameValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getDestinationStation().getStationName();

            platFormName.setText(platformValue);

            schDepart.setText(schDepartValue);
            expDepart.setText(schExpectValue);
            arrival.setText(arrivalValue);
            exparrival.setText(exparrivalValue);
            stationName.setText(stationNameValue);
            return v;
    }

    public void notifySetDataChanged() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Comment: do yu hit the webservice from the same class?? sir

Answer (score 2):

It is because your Adapter is still holding the old reference to the dataset which is emptied when you call `data.getData().clear();`

To clarify, when you first create your adapter,

```
adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, data.getData());
```

You are passing an ArrayList, data.getData() to your adapter, and that is the ArrayList your Adapter will read data from.

Now, when you have received new data, you pointed data to localData, but your adapter is not aware of this.

```
@Override
public void getWebserviceResponse(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("timer", result);
    data.getData().clear();
    deparaturedaseboarddto localData = new Gson().fromJson(result,deparaturedaseboarddto.class);
    data=localData;
    adapter.notifySetDataChanged();
}
```

So instead of doing `data = localData;`, you should do `data.addAll(localData.getData());` then call notifyDataSetChanged();

Basically you want to use one single ArrayList and just keep removing data from it and adding new data to it.